# Adding specific class when at page top to scrolling code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which adds/removes `.nav-down` and `.nav-up` to #nav when the user scrolls.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var didScroll;
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var delta = 5;
  var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) { didScroll = true; });

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
  hasScrolled();
  didScroll = false;
  }
 }, 150);

function hasScrolled() {
  if($( window ).width() > 768) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight ) {

    // Scroll Down
    $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');

} else {

    // Scroll Up
    if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    }
 }

} else {
$('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
}
lastScrollTop = st;
}
});
```

I want add another class called `.extra` to #nav when the function adds `.nav-down` to #nav. BUT I only want it to add it when the user is at the top of the page, and not add it any other time. So it only gets added when the user is at the top of the page.

Comment: Sounds good. What have you tried? What value do you think `$(this).scrollTop()` would have at the top of the page?

Comment: As mentioned below, I tried the $(window).scrollTop() method in a seperate function, but the functionality seems to interfere with each other when it's in two seperate functions. Most noticeably when the user scrolls UP to the top, it doesn't apply, but when you refresh the page it works

Comment: Why are you putting it in two separate functions, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) on `scrollTop()`. It is 0 when you are at the top of the page, so you should just have a script that will set the class when `$(window).scrollTop()` is 0, and remove it otherwise.

For example:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll === 0) {
        $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
    }
});
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: I tried this before, the problem is that both codes would be running at the same time on the same div, so it doesn't seem to work as expected. I was thinking it would be smoother if it could be applied inside the current code

Comment: So why not just add the same code I provided inside the `if` statement where you're adding `nav-down`? Or, if you need both conditions to be true, you could just change your `if` statement to say `if( st + $(window).height() < $(document).height() && $(window).scrollTop() === 0){ // code }`, right?

Comment: Then I'd have to add another else statement when I want it .nav-down to attach but not .extra (since they wont be at the top of the page). THe issue I  am having it that it only seems to apply once when the page is loaded. When the user scrolls to the top it doesn't change, unless the page is reloaded

Comment: @user3550879 I just got a notification that you accepted this answer. Does that mean you've been able to make it work?

Comment: I haven't made it work, but it has lead me to a better way to go about/accomplish what I want. The answer you provided in the comment helped a lot, I can only give you credit by accepting the answer above though

Comment: Fair enough! Would you mind posting the solution you found? I'm kind of curious haha

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a solution, But I'm trying to include three 'ifs' in the code. Can't seem to get it to function though, adding another 'scroll up' function when the user is at the top of the page